# jquery menu script. hide() not working

Tags: jquery, hide

i'm trying to write some script about jquery menu. My problem is, that jquery hide() function not working. My code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#topmenu ul li').mouseover(function(){ 
            $('#topmenu ul li').removeClass('show');
            $('.child').hide();
            $(this).addClass('show');
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('id').replace("parent", "#child");
            $(currentTab).addClass('showtab');
            $(currentTab).show();
            return false;
        });
        $('#topmenu ul li').mouseout(function(){
            var currentParent = $(this).attr('id').replace("parent", "#parent");
            var currentTab = $(this).attr('id').replace("parent", "#child");
            $(currentTab).hide(); <---- this not works
            if ($(currentTab).hasClass('showtab')) {
                $(currentTab).show();
                $(currentTab).mouseout(function(){
                    /*alert($(this).height());*/
                    $(this).removeClass('showtab');
                    $(currentParent).removeClass('show');
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            }

            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
</head>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="topmenu">
        <ul>
            <li id="parent1" class="parent first">First</li>
            <li id="parent2" class="parent">second</li>
            <li id="parent3" class="parent">third</li>
            <li id="parent4" class="parent">fourth</li>
            <li id="parent5" class="parent">fift</li>
            <li id="parent6" class="parent last">sixt</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="child1" class="child">
                blah blah blah 1        
        </div>
        <div id="child2" class="child">
                blah blah blah 2                            
        </div>
        <div id="child3" class="child">
                blah blah blah 3
        </div>
        <div id="child4" class="child">
                blah blah blah 4
        </div>
        <div id="child5" class="child">
                blah blah blah 5    
        </div>
        <div id="child6" class="child">
                blah blah blah 6
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I note that you edited to change the title to indicate this was solved. What you should do is accept the correct answer, or answer yourself and accept if none of the given answers was correct. That will then mark the question as answered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `.hide` works fine, but just two lines later (inside the `if`) you imminently `show` it again.

The whole `if ($(currentTab).hasClass('showtab')) {` block is very confusing. What is it supposed to do? Repeatingly assigned another `mouseover` without removing it is a bad thing to do. After a while the tabs will have dozens of handlers assigned to them.

When you leave the whole `if` block out, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You're not loading jquery anywhere in that.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Seems to work fine when you actually load the library. :)